# Equation of line from two points (general solution)

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, angle

I'm looking for the equation of the line that goes through points $A(x_1, y_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2)$, expressed in the format $a + bx = y$ where $b$ is the slope of the line. The solutions that I've found start by calculating the slope with $b = \frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}$, but this equation has no solution for when $x_1=x_2$. Is there a general solution that includes vertical and horizontal lines?

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal lines are included in the usual form, with the slope being zero since $y_1 = y_2$ for every $y$ on the horizontal case, so $b=0$ and $y=a$. Now you cannot include vertical lines for a lot of reasons. First and foremost, vertical lines are not functions i.e. there is no dependent variable $y=y(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need at least two unique points to find the equation of a line.
We know that equation of line given two points $\displaystyle ( x_{1} ,y_{1})$ and $\displaystyle ( x_{2} ,y_{2})$ is given by
$\displaystyle y-y_{1} =\frac{y_{2} -y_{1}}{x_{2} -x_{1}}( x-x_{1})$
However when $\displaystyle x_{2} =x_{1}$ you may say that the slope is undefined, but when we rearrange this equation we get $\displaystyle ( y-y_{1})( x_{2} -x_{1}) =( y_{2} -y_{1})( x-x_{1})$ and now pluggin $\displaystyle x_{2} =x_{1}$ we get that $\displaystyle x-x_{1} =0$ or the equation of line is $\displaystyle x=x_{1}$

Comment: Thank you. When you rearrange for (y−y1)(x2−x1)=(y2−y1)(x−x1), you multiply both sides of the equation by (x2−x1), which we know to be zero. I thought multiplying equations by 0 was not allowed. Could you please explain why it was permissible in this case?

Comment: If you do the derivation of this equation of the line, the rearranged part comes first in the derivation.  Then we divide both sides by $x_2-x_1$ to get the widely known equation. Generally yes, multiplying by zero is not allowed but in this case its fine, because in the derivation of the equation of line we assume that $x_2 \neq x_1$

Comment: Makes sense now, thank you.

Comment: Extras: To avoid such ambiguity's its better to use the equation of line as $ax+by+c=0$ as there you wont be encountering such anomalies.